# URL Hyperlink for opening UPI Apps in mobile with callback response for transaction status

Tags: url, hyperlink, upi

I know that by following an URL Hyperlink like the following, we can open UPI apps for in mobile.

```html
<a href="upi://pay?pa=upiaddress@okhdfcbank&pn=JohnDoe&cu=INR">Buy Now</a>
```

But my question is how to get the transaction status from there? I need to track which payment/transaction is success and which is failure.

I tried reading NPCI documents, but did not find any solution.

Comment: It is not possible to do. You need an SDK and the required infrastructure with authentication and stuff.